# PUG NodeJS Express Front End / Backend no connection

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Hello i have two NodeJS running on my sever

please this is only a dev machine not production so i know parsing the form data etc etc

App.js - Backend Express Sever running on port 4000

index.js - Front End PUG/Express running on port 8000

i can access the frontend on something.mydomain.com

but when i try to ajax the backend with 'POST' to localhost:4000/Whatever/Whatever

it doesnt allow me to.

as in it tries to load locahost from the WWW external not internal
login.js

```js
const serverurl = "http://localhost:4000";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login').click(function () {
        var data = {};
        data.username = $('#inputusername').val();
        data.password = $('#inputpassword').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: serverurl+'/user/login'
            , type: 'POST'
            , data: JSON.stringify(data)
            , contentType: 'application/json'
        })
            .done(function (data) {

                if (data[0].response == '1') {
                    alert("Logged In");
                    Cookies.set('user', data[0].name);
                    Cookies.set('location', data[0].location);
                    Cookies.set('role', data[0].role);
                    $(location).attr('href', '/home');
                } else if(data[0].response == '0') alert("Username or Password Incorrect")
            });


    });
```

[frontend request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njiKo.png)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: By default, browser makers allow Ajax calls only to the same origin, or domain. A call from a script in a page served by localhost:8000 to a server at localhost:4000 involves two different domains. So you need something like CORS.

Comment: thank you for this comment. so would cors work if i serve a website at subdomain.mydomain.com which reverse proxys to localhost:8000, then i want to ajax localhost:4000. I installed cors on both front end and back end but no success.

Comment: Reverse proxies shouldn't affect, as the original request urls are retained. I don't see how you can Ajax to localhost:4000 from the client. The client gets the web pages from subdomain.mydomain.com (app running at port 8000). The Ajax call has to be made to something like api.mydomain.com (app running at port 4000). I believe the browser will make a pre-flight request to api.mydomain.com to see if the call will be accepted. See the link in the answer given by Selcuk. The CORS package should need to be at your backend server only.

Answer (score 0):

You got CORS error. You can reach [more info about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).
My solution is using for Express.js [CORS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Your main js file should be like:

```
// app.js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
```